# Where can I find GKE CRDs?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm, helm3, kind

Trying to run `helm/chart-testing-action` in a GitHub workflow using `kind`. For the charts I require some GKE CRDs though. Any place I can find them?

Comment: Which CRD's do you need exactly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kubernetes [client libraries](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/client-libraries/) can be used to access custom resources. Not all client libraries support custom resources. The Go and Python client libraries do.

When you add a custom resource, you can access it using:

1. kubectl
2. The kubernetes dynamic client.
3. A REST client that you write.
4. A client generated using [Kubernetes client generation tools](https://github.com/kubernetes/code-generator) (generating one is an advanced undertaking, but some projects may provide a client along with the CRD or AA).

Refer to this document on [Custom Resources](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/api-extension/custom-resources/#customresourcedefinitions) for more detailed information.