# CRDs of GKE for local development with minikube

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, minikube, helm3, kind

I'm trying to running my project (that supposed to) deploy on GKE in my local environment with minikube (Docker-Engine) for sake of development and testing, however when I type `helm install` it tells me I need to install CRDs like `BackendConifg`, `PodMonitoring`, `ManagedCertificate`... etc.  first in order to install charts with those kind

Is there any place to get those CRD yaml file or any way for minikube to import those CRDs? Thanks!

Possible related question (unanswered): [Where can I find GKE CRDs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73134236/where-can-i-find-gke-crds)

Answer (score 1):

GKE CRD's cannot be deployed outside of GKE. Especially the ones you mentioned (BackendConfig, ManagedCertificates...) because they only made sense when used with GKE.